# Annihilator set in regular expression

Tags: regular-language

Given that ø+anything is an indentity, therefore ø + a = a.

What exactly is the result of (ø+ øbb)?

Comment: You need to define the problem for which the regular expression is to be used. One or more examples would be helpful. For each, be sure to show the desired result. I don't understand what `"ø* = e(epsolon)`, and `(a+b+ø) = (a+b)`" means. `ø*` in a regular expression means, "match `ø` zero or more times". I don't see how the picture adds anything.

Comment: my apologies, the tag is wrong, this is a regular language issue where ø means an anhilitator set. in a multiplication ø.a for instance, ø anihilates a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty set ∅ is kinda sorta like the number zero. If you add zero to anything, you get what you started with. (That is, ∅ + x = x.) Similarly, if you multiply anything by zero, you get zero. This is also true for languages: ∅x = ∅ for any x. The reason why is that the concatenation of two languages is the language of all strings you can make by grabbing something from the first set and something from the second set and concatenating them together, and in the case of the empty set there are no strings to pick.

(More abstractly: language union and concatenation form a semiring with the empty set as the zero element and {ε} as an identity element.)

Comment: So, my resulting expression, will be then (∅)(a+b)c+bø*. cd + (a+b+ø), or just (a+b)c+bø*. cd + (a+b+ø), thats what i dont understand